# Getting data out of unbootable Parrot

Tags: debian, boot, dual-boot, data-recovery

I have a parrot which cannot totally boot, the beginning graphical screen pops up but no further. I cannot enter text mode. I have Windows dual booted aside parrot. Any idea how I can get my relevant data out.

If you need more information I can answer any questions.

Comment: is this partition encrypted?

Comment: I am not sure. Can I check on Windows in disk management?

Comment: make a live usb with some linux and try to boot

Comment: That's what I was think boot another Linux. Mount another filesystem get my data. And delete the partition for the old one